# MySQL update without primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm looking to figure out how i can update a row like a LIMIT 2,2 on a select
there is a little example:

```
col1 | col2
 5      10
 5      10
 5      10
```

I want to update the 2nd row like this:

```
col1 | col2
 5      10
 1      10
 5      10
```

i know the row number so i want something like that:

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = 1
WHERE col1 = 5
LIMIT 2, 1
```

we cant use limit but i know this is achievable, HeidiSQL can do it and i'm trying to figure out how they are doing

thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as a second row in a table.  Tables represent *unordered* sets, so you need a column that specifies the ordering.  Hence, your question doesn't make sense.  You can update *any* of the rows.

Comment: you are right, i'm idiot, all i need is a limit 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to update particular rows, you need a column or columns that can be used as primary key.

SQL works on sets of rows and you can only update rows that can be identified as belonging to the set.

For example, you can

```
UPDATE Customers SET Preferred=True WHERE TotalSales > 1000
```

which will set the "Preferred" flag for any customers that have sales over 1000. This might be one customer or a million or none.

The  only way to do the single row update you asked about is to have some way to identify the row. In many database servers you can configure an IDENTITY or SEQUENCE column that will auto-assign each row a unique ID.

You can add an ID column with the IDENTITY property set, which would get you:

```
ID | col1 | col2
 1    5     10
 2    5     10
 3    5     10
```

So updating that particular row would be:

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = 1 WHERE ID = 2
```

Comment: A row can be updated if there's a key that identifies it. Typically the most used one is the primary key, but any other key can work as well. For example any `UNIQUE` key would work.